# Teradata - Create two rows from one

Tags: teradata

I need to create two rows with different keys from one using SQL.  I have been unable to accomplish this.

I have one ELEMENT which needs to be separated into two.

- GAAP: Should only be populated with Special Handling when it is in
  the company A, B, C, or D.
- Statutory: Should ALWAYS equal what is in the parent (Special Handling)

My current code does not work because of the case statement.  If it is in A,B,C,D then it is assigned correctly, but the second one does not.  It only picks up the other companies.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME = 'Special Handling'  AND AB.UNIT_COMPANY_NME IN ('A','B','C','D')) THEN 'GAAP Special Handling'
    WHEN AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME = 'Special Handling' THEN 'Statutory Special Handling' 
    ELSE AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME
END AS DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME,  
sum(AB.DATA_ELEMENT_AMT) as DATA_ELEMENT_AMT
FROM
```

Any suggestions?

**Update**

**Data IN:** Special Handling   -3727286.720000

**Data OUT:** GAAP Special Handling -3727286.720000

Statutory Special Handling  -3727286.720000

Comment: You need to elaborate on your requirements, your CASE looks ok to me. Can you show some example data & expected result?

Comment: The CASE statement stops processing on the first condition met. You need to provide more example detail data than you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

For a single input record, you are expecting two output records. The basic idea you are missing here is that how much ever logic you put in there, a single query like this is going to give you a single output record for a single input record.

What you need is a union:

```
SELECT
  'GAAP Special Handling' AS DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME,  
  sum(AB.DATA_ELEMENT_AMT) as DATA_ELEMENT_AMT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE 
  AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME = 'Special Handling'  AND 
  AB.UNIT_COMPANY_NME IN ('A','B','C','D')

UNION ALL

SELECT
  CASE WHEN AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME = 'Special Handling' 
      THEN 'Statutory Special Handling' 
      ELSE AB.DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME 
  END AS DATA_ELEMENT_BUSINESS_NME,  
  sum(AB.DATA_ELEMENT_AMT) as DATA_ELEMENT_AMT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Better use `UNION ALL` to avoid DISTINCT processing.